# Distribute Custom App in Ios (without adding to AppStore)

Tags: ios, publish, mobile-application

I have a mobile app developed in Flutter for a company. How can I distribute it to them instead of publishing it in the app store? I have an Apple Business Manager and a developer account in separate Apple IDs. How can I distribute to that particular client? Please help. (All the devices are self-owned by users of the app).
I have read all the available documents, either I didn't understand them properly or did not read the appropriate one.

I understand that through AppStore Connet, we can publish the app to AppStore. But I don't want to publish it publicly.

Can anyone tell me the steps I should go through?

Comment: The company needs to sign up for Apple Business Manager. You submit the app to App Store Connect and get it reviewed as usual but you distribute it as a private app, made available to the company's ABM id. It is up to the company as to how they distribute the app to their employees. The easiest/best way is via an MDM. The  more difficult alternative is they need to provide redemption codes to their employees.

Comment: Watch https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304